# "Do my best for something to happen" is grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

“I did my best for them to add (something) in the list” is that a grammatically correct way to convey the intended meaning, which is (I convinced them) to add that thing to the list?

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase would be easily understood but this is not common usage. I suggest:

I did my best to *convince* them to add (something) to the list.

Other possibilities:

*I did my best to persuade them to ...
I did my best to get them to ...*

Answer (score -1):

To "do one's best" expresses volition or an action/result on your behalf, but for "something to happen" does not. More generally, any phrase of which I am not the subject after "I did my best" doesn't make total sense for exactly that reason; even though there's no syntactical error in such a statement, there is certainly a semantical one.

In order to bridge this gap, rather than saying "I will do my best for A to X" (where A is another subject and X is some action to be performed by A), you can say "I will do my best **to get** A to X". (Alternatively, use "to make A X" or, like chasly suggested, say "to persuade A to X" or "to convince A to X" should the context deem those appropriate; you could hardly say "I did my best to persuade it to rain" even though someone doing a rain dance is certainly "doing their best to make it rain".) That way, you express your volition to bring about the state described in the latter clause, so the two "sides" of the sentence match.

Some examples of good usage:

- I will do my best to eat well.
- I did my best to keep the interviewer interested in my various projects.

(Since both "eat" and "keep" refer to actions to be performed by you, these are both fine as-is.)

- I will do my best to get him to eat well.
- The politician did his best to persuade voters that he was the best candidate.
- Will you do your best to get her on my side?

(c.f. "for him to eat well", "for voters to believe that...", "for her to be...". All of these latter options seem a bit stilted due to the subject mismatch.)

Comment: Have you checked into the possibility that "for" might be used in this context as a shortcut for "in order for"? Both are quite commonly used after "I did my best" and variants. This doesn't make them right, but does give them a certain legitimacy.

Comment: I haven't heard "doing one's best for [subordinate clause]" much before, and looking online hasn't been particularly fruitful. You're definitely right that common parlance legitimizes what might be considered incorrect, though. On the other hand, the phrase "doing one's best in order for A to X" seems subtly different from "doing one's best to X (or cause A to X)" in that the former expresses the purpose for *doing* whereas the latter expresses what is being done; I think it comes down to something about the way phrasal verbs behave in general.